# Find UITableViewScrollPosition to properly scroll to a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, scroll

I am trying to scroll to a particular UITableViewCell and it's works but sometimes if row is at the bottom of UITableView then it fails to scroll at that particular row. What I want to know is how I can identify which scroll position should be passed into the below method ?

```
- (void)scrollToObject:(AdvisoriesModel*)output {
    NSInteger index = -1;
    for (AdvisoriesModel* memberSites in self.AMAList) {
        if ([memberSites.amaId isEqualToString:output.amaId]) {

            index = [self.AMAList indexOfObject:memberSites];
            break;
        }
    }

    if (index != -1) {
        @try {
            NSIndexPath* indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0];
            [self.tableAMA scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone animated:YES];
            [self.tableAMA selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
            double delayInSeconds = 1.0;
            dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
            dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
                // Put your code here
                [self.tableAMA deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
            });
        } @catch (NSException *exception) {

            NSLog(@"Exception occured while scrolling to Custom Fly Site %@",[exception description]);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Your logic is working for visible cells only ?

Comment: yes it's working for visible cells only